# Does a DR plan need to be in place for an AlwaysOn availability group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, disaster-recovery

I have two SQL servers 2022 in a normal availability group. I have heard that AG is capable of disaster recovery. Is this true or do I need to make an extra plan?
Another question: Why is Failover Cluster Instance not capable for disaster recovery?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Hector,
yes, AGs are suitable for DR, usually configured in asynchronous replication.
This can be achieved setting the DR node in the same cluster and setting the Listener with multiple IPs, one for the primary site and another for the DR site.

[microsft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is Failover Cluster Instance not capable for disaster recovery?

Because it's not protecting against disasters with data center like:

- fire,
- power outage,
- network disconnection

Also it do not protect against SAN failures.

Comment: Add human error to the list. Dropping wrong object or error in `where` for update/ delete is a common mistake. Neither failover cluster nor availability group will help there, backups are needed.